# Create a bundle in vendors in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, bundle, hwioauthbundle

I am trying to create a bundle in vendors in Symfony2.

MyBundle(MineUserBundle) needs to inherit other two bundle in vendors `FOSUserBundle` and `HWIOAuthBundle`.

How to get inherit both bundles properties, templates  etc in Mybundle?

```
vendors
   FOSUserBundle 
   HWIOAuthBundle
   MineUserBundle
```

Here `MineUserBundle` needs to have all features of other two bundle.

How to get the process work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using namespaces it does not mater into which folder you are going to deploy your Bundle. Just include use statements in your bundle with ones you need:

```
use Path\To\FOS\UserBundle;
use Path\ToHWIO\AuthBundle;
```

And you can extend whatever you need.

But if you really want to install your bundle to `vendor` directory, then you have to configure define it in your `deps` file.

```
[YourVendorYouBundle]
    git=git@github.com:yourRepository/YourVendorYouBundle.git
    target=/bundles/YourVendor/YouBundle
```

Comment: Is it possible to install other two bundles with MyBundle deps. i.e I only use  MyBundle in deps or composer file, need to automatically install other two bundles in vendors. Whether it can achieved by any alteration in any file in MyBundle?

Comment: No, it is not possible, AFAIK. You have to define your deps manually. Don't know about Composer though

Comment: In HWIOAuthBundle, the user login response are getting in `UserResponseInterface.php` of HWIOAuthBundle itself. I need response get in MyBundle and add new function in `UserResponseInterface.php` from MyBundle. How do this?

Comment: the `deps` file is no longer standard practice in symfony2, you should be using composer instead

Comment: @Jaitsu questions is tagged as `Symfony-2.0`

Comment: @thecatontheflat AFAIK symfony2.1 questions aren't tagged separately, although they probably should be given the differences